# metriks log to file not working

Tags: ruby, code-metrics

I wrote a basic program to test the ruby metriks gem

```
require 'metriks'
require 'metriks/reporter/logger'

@registry = Metriks::Registry.new

@logger = Logger.new('/tmp/metrics.log')
@reporter = Metriks::Reporter::Logger.new(:logger => @logger)
@reporter.start

@registry.meter('tasks').mark
print "Hello"
@registry.meter('tasks').mark

@reporter.stop
```

After i execute the program, there is nothing in the log other than it got created.

```
$ cat /tmp/metrics.log
# Logfile created on 2015-06-15 14:23:40 -0700 by logger.rb/44203
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either pass in your own registry while instantiating `Metriks::Reporter::Logger` or use the deafult registry (`Metrics::Resgitry.default`) if you are using a logger to log metrics.

Also the default log write interval is 60 seconds, your code completes before that so even if everything is setup okay it won't get recorded. So, since you want to use your own registry, this should work for you (I'm adding a little sleep since I'm gonna use an interval of 1 second) :

```
require 'metriks'
require 'metriks/reporter/logger'

@registry = Metriks::Registry.new

@logger = Logger.new('/tmp/metrics.log')
@reporter = Metriks::Reporter::Logger.new(:logger => @logger, 
                                          :registry => @registry
                                          :interval => 1)
@reporter.start

@registry.meter('tasks').mark
print "Hello"
@registry.meter('tasks').mark

# Just giving it a little time so the metrics will be recorded.
sleep 2

@reporter.stop
```

But I don't really think short intervals are good.

UPDATE : Also I think `@reporter.write` will help you write down the logs instantly regardless of the time interval. So you don't have to use `sleep` (better).